# Specified sort in R

Tags: r

```
id <- c(1:10)

title <- c("Director", "Manager", "Associate", "Director", "Associate", "Director", "Manager", "Director", "Associate", "Director")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,title))

df[order(title),]
```

I want to sort this data by designation, but not alphabetically but in some specific order like (Director>Manager>Analyst) using tool R.

Answer (score -1):

You can refactor title using user-specified levels

```
df$title<-factor(df$title,levels=c("Director","Manager","Associate"))
df[order(df$title),]
```